# How to call a function inside an array that save matches rules

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm trying to call a function inside one array but using the matches.

I have a string with text ($text) and 2 arrays.

The array A have rules for find content:

```
$a=array('rule1', 'rule2', rule3');
```

The array b have:

```
$b=array("Rule 1 return the matches: $1 $2 $3", "Rule 2: $1 $2 $3", "Rule 3 $1 $2 $3");
```

And with a foreach loop, the arrays make the work:

```
foreach($a AS $key => $val){
    while(preg_match($val, $text)){
        $text = preg_replace($val, $b[$key], $text);
    }
}
```

Exist a method? for do with the array b:

```
$b=array("Rule 1 return the matches:".calltofunction("$1$2$3")."", ...
```

I tried use \1 and $1 for the matches, but when i call to the function every time the function receives the string "$1$2$3" or "\1\2\3" but not the matched values.

Regards!

Comment: You'd probably have to _eval_ that if php supports it. Btw, you haven't shown the apparent constant regex. There is an association between the regex capture groups and the key, but I don't think it can be done this way since `$key` would have to be a capture group. Or, I'm missing something.

Comment: show real regex or use preg_replace /e option

Comment: The `/e` modifier/option is deprecated, `preg_replace_callback` should be used in its place. I don't know if that would be applicable here though, can't really see what OP is after.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, i searched and this seems not posible like i'm trying. I used preg_replace_callback for every item of the array and now it works! Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems not possible, the array A that save the rules, yes can be used for save the rules. But for the B is needed make the custom function per each one.

```
function Myfunction($text) {
    return preg_replace_callback($a[the num id],
    function($match) {
        return "This return this matches: $match[1] $match[2] $match[3]";
    }
    , $text);
}
```